# Power BI Running total horizontally

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am working with Power BI tables and I am not being able to calculate  balance "Running total" like I need.

I was searching in Stack Overflow and other webpages and I always find the same solution for a very similar situation, which is not this.

First of all, this is my table:

[image: First table]

I found in this and [other sites](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Cumulative-Total/td-p/43115) the same solution:

```
Running Total COLUMN =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'My table'[Accounting Balance] ),
        ALL ( 'My table' ),
       'My table'[Date] <= EARLIER ( 'My table'[Date] ))
```

This would work whenever I need to sum the rows vertically, which is not my case. Indeed, I need to sum the valu horizontally:

[image: Second table]

Any suggestions?

**Edit 1**:

This is what I need:

[image: Result table]

So if you take a close look to this table it has the resulting calculation of each column for each vendor like:

1. **Vendor 1** owed $200 on January 2017
2. **Vendor 1** owed $0 on February 2017 because he made a $200 payment
3. **Vendor 1** owed $50 on March 2017 because $0 + $50
4. **Vendor 1** owed $50 on April 2017 because he didn't make any payment.
5. **Vendor 1** owes $50 in total.
6. etc

Comment: Do you just want the end column to be a "Totals" column? Or did you want to add/transform rows so the value of each month is the running total of the original values?

Comment: @Mistella, that is exactly what I need, calculate the running totals for each column for each vendor in each month.

Comment: This is a bit of an X Y question. **If at all possible**, the best solution would be to unpivot your source table so that each date doesn't need its own column. I can explain how to do this, but wanted to ask if you're willing to do that first.

Comment: Alexis, thanks for answering, It's not up to me, I am getting the data from an OLAP cube on my company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done in Power Query as I don't have BI, but I assume the M-Code will work just as well.  It will also auto adjust if you refresh the query as you add/delete columns, so there is no need to reference each column individually.

You add a Custom Column which sums all the columns except the "Vendor/Month"

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Vendor/Month", type text}, {"Jan-17", Int64.Type}, {"Feb-17", Int64.Type}, {"Mar-17", Int64.Type}, {"Apr-17", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sum" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Changed Type",
      "Total",
  each List.Sum(
    Record.ToList(
      Record.SelectFields(
      _,
      List.RemoveItems(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), {"Vendor/Month"})))))
in
    #"Sum"
```

This is the Custom Column Dialog:

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the hard work, but I think you are missing the point since I need to do the calculation horizontally by vendor / month.

Comment: @MartinFernandez  But it matches your "This is what I need" screenshot. Except for the Totals row at the bottom, which you can just add to the table.

Comment: Okay, but I am seeing the "And this is the result" screenshot and it does not match with the "This is what I need" screenshot. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MartinFernandez Each Row is added in the total column.  I figured the numbers in the `Month` columns were manually entered, and just used the set from your `what I have`.  If that is not the case, I guess I don't understand how you get the changes in the `Feb`, `Mar` and `Apr` columns that you show between the sets of data.  I thought you were just adding up the rows.

Comment: Indeed, I just used a case scenario because in real life I have three years data. One row represents a vendor in a timeline (in months) so the balance changes depending on the payments the vendor makes.

Comment: @MartinFernandez If you don't want the entries in the rows added up in a Totals column at the end, then I don't understand what you want.

Comment: @MartinFernandez If you want this to be done if you should change an item in the table, you will need a formula in the Totals Column rather than refreshing the query.

Comment: Ok, whatever, I marking this as the correct answer but I will have to investigate more. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Since it was 3 years ago, you probably don't need this anymore, but I'm gonna leave it here in case someone looks for an answer:
You need to convert the column names (Jan-17 etc.) to dates (1/1/2017), unpivot this in PowerQuery and then you will be able to create a running total DAX measure (it can be a quick measure too, this is how I created it):

Hours running total in Month =
CALCULATE(
SUM('My table'[Accounting Balance]),
FILTER(
ALLSELECTED('My table'[Date]),
ISONORAFTER('My table'[Date], MAX('My table'[Date]), DESC)
)
)

Put it into the the Values bucket of the matrix visual (with months as columns and vendors as rows).

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a big assumption here: That "Totals" the column does NOT need a "Total" row.

If not, then isn't the Column defined as shown:

```
Totals = Table1[Jan-17]+Table1[Feb-17]+Table1[Mar-17]
```

[image: PowerBI Totals Column]

Comment: It's right, it doesn't need a Total row, but I have used three months as an example. In real life, I have three years or more (in that format)... Therefore I can't just add manually their names.

Comment: Cool - be sure to define scope in your problem statements too. Sounds like you need this: [PowerBI Sum Rows](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Sum-values-of-multiple-columns-per-row/td-p/356026). The fatal assumption here is that you're not adding new columns regularly, which you'd want to avoid in PowerBI anyways.

Comment: I have three years data, where I have 12 months by year, these are not dynamically created, but they are filtered regularly so I wouldn't sum all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested earlier by Alexis Olson, you should import the 'table' you get from the OLAP-cube into the Power Query Editor and unpivot it. You would start with this:

[image]

Use a script like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\927085\Documents\Marco\SO\SO18-10-1.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet3_Sheet = Source{[Item="myTable",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet3_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, {"Column4", type any}, {"Column5", type any}, {"Column6", type any}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"Totals"}),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Removed Columns",1),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Bottom Rows", {"Vendor/Month"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Custom", each "1-"&[Attribute]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", type date}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Custom", "Month"}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type2",{{"Value", "Accounting Balance"}, {"Vendor/Month", "Vendor"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1"
```

And the resulting table would be this:

[image]

Then create the following maesure:

```
RunningTotal = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( myTable[Accounting Balance] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'myTable', myTable[Vendor] ),
        'myTable'[Month] <= SELECTEDVALUE ( myTable[Month] )
    )
)
```

In a matrix visual put Vendor on rows, Month on columns and the [RunningTotal] on Values.

[image]